# UltraEdit: Deleting all lines under a certain length with \n and or \r

Tags: regex, pcre, ultraedit

I have a massive text file and want to remove all lines that are less than 6 characters long.

I tried the following search string (Regular expressions - Perl)

```
^.{0,5}\n\r$   -- string not found

^.{0,5}\n\r    -- string not found

^.{0,5}$       -- leaves blank lines

^.{0,5}$\n\r   -- string not found

^.{0,5}$\r     -- leaves blank lines

^.{0,5}$\r\n   -- **worked**
```

My question is why should the last one work and the 4th one not work? Why should the 5th one leave blank lines.

Thanks.

Comment: UltraEdit indicates the line terminator type in status bar at bottom of main application window for active file with **DOS**, **UNIX**, **MAC**. See UltraEdit forum topic [DOS/UNIX/MAC line terminator indication in status bar](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15214) with more information about this indication in status bar. And take a look also on [UE symbol explanations for line teminators](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because  `^.{0,5}$\n\r` is not the same as `^.{0,5}$\r\n`.

- `\n\r` is a linefeed followed by carriage return.
- `\r\n`  is a carriage return followed by linefeed - a popular [line ending combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) of characters. Specifically `\r\n` is used by the MS-DOS and Windows family of operating systems, among others.

Comment: All text files follow this sequence?

Comment: DOS/Windows has traditionally been CR/LF (`\r\n`) while Unix systems are just a bare LF (`\n`).  Macs before OS X used a bare CR (`\r`).  I'm not aware of any systems that used LF/CR (`\n\r`).

Comment: @tomlogic According to [Wikipedia's Newline article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) Acorn and RiscOS used it in certain applications.

Answer (score 1):

In multiline mode, `^` is a metacharacter that matches *Begin of String* and 
can also match after a newline.

Likewise, `$` matches *End of String* and these too:

```
          \r\n
         ^    ^
here ----+-or-+
```

or

```
            \n
         ^    ^
here ----+-or-+
```

`$` will try to match before newline if it can (depends on other parts of the regex).

You can use that to advantage like this regex

`^.{0,5}$(\r?\n)*` which will match end of string *AND* optional successive linebreaks.